# iptables outgoing drop works but incoming drop seems not working. Why?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have this setup:

Host machine: 10.40.10.3
Device that is connected to host machine: 10.40.10.6

The traffic that I capture is repeatedly this:

```
IP 10.40.10.3.53258 > 10.40.10.6.2883: UDP, length 12
IP 10.40.10.6.2883 > 10.40.10.3.53258: UDP, length 9
```

When I write this in iptables, the traffic is blocked (I do not capture any thing any more):

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.40.10.6 -p udp --sport 53258 --dport 2883 -j DROP
```

But actually what I want to block is "incoming" packets. So, I write this in iptables but this does not work:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.40.10.6 -p udp --sport 2883 --dport 53258 -j REJECT
```

Literally, with this rule what I try to do is:
Block all incoming traffic from device with IP 10.40.10.6 - port 2883 to the host machine port 53258.

In both cases, iptables has only 1 rule.

Why is the second one not working? How to do?

Comment: Note: dropping the incoming packet happens *after* tcpdump captures it. So just using tcpdump capture on an interface is not a correct method to know if the rule worked. There might be no actual problem, but it's difficult to know with what was provided

Answer (score 0):

The -D option deletes a rule. Try -I to insert the rule at the beginning of INPUT, or -A to append it.

Comment: Sorry, -D was a silly mistake when writing the question. Of course, it is -A. Question edited.